# Kotlin Types, Subtypes, and Supertypes vs Classes, Subclasses and Superclasses

Tags: kotlin

I am learning about subtypes and supertypes in Kotlin, and initially assumed that these terms meant inherited and parent classes. But after reading [this post from JetBrains](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/9689), I am not sure I understand exactly what they mean by subtyping.

The post explains that `Any` is a subtype of `Any?` (makes sense), `Number` is a subtype of `Any`, and `Int` is a subtype of `Number`. So far so good (`Any?` -> `Any` -> `Number` -> `Int`), and (`Any?` -> `Number?` -> `Int?`).

But notice diagram # 5:

[image]

This diagram (and the accompanying text) imply and explain that `Number` is a subtype of its nullable counterpart `Number?`, and that `Int` is also a subtype of its nullable counterpart `Int?`. This sounds intuitive, until you remember that `Int` is also a subtype of `Number`, and `Number` a subtype of `Any`! This is in direct contradiction with the Kotlin docs which specify that

*Kotlin supports single-parent class inheritance - so each class (except the root class Any) has got exactly one parent class, called a superclass.*

I am left assuming that subtypes are not children classes per se (a single class can be a subtype of more than one parent class at once maybe?). If so, can someone clarify for me exactly what is meant by "subtypes" and "supertypes" in Kotlin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Types are not the same thing as classes. Types are used to restrict values of variables, properties and function parameters, or function return values. The type might match a class, but it might also match an interface.

A class can have only one direct super**class**, but a type can have many direct super**types**, which might be any of

- The direct superclass of a class type, and any superclass of that superclass, etc. up to `Any`
- Interfaces that a class type implements, and superinterfaces of those interfaces
- Superinterfaces of interface types
- `Any`, even if the type is an interface type (interfaces don't have a superclass)
- Nullable versions of the type or any supertype

And subtypes would be

- Subclasses, or subclasses of those subclasses, etc. of a class type
- Subinterfaces of an interface type
- The non-null version of a nullable type or its subtypes.
- The `Nothing` object which is treated as a subtype of everything.

In your example, `Number` is not a superclass of `Int`. It is an interface, so it is only a supertype. The direct superclass of `Int` is `Any`.

Comment: Good answer!  And to join a couple of the dots: if `T` is a class, then both `T` and `T?` are types — with `T` a subtype of `T?`, as mentioned.  (The difference is effectively ‘erased’ at runtime, in a similar way to type parameters.)